# DS open failure mode for trench MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

After switching on and off few times for a trench MOSFET in a motor application, D-S shows open. After decap to check the bonding, the bonding wires are all good. What might cause this kind of failure?

Comment: overvoltage, overcurrent, cosmic rays, cursed engineers...

Comment: You blew it up, that's what happened. You must have exceeded the maximum ratings. A motor, did you rely only on the internal diode to handle the flyback current or did you add extra diodes ? A datasheet of the MOSFET, motor, operating conditions etc would help to make meaningfull suggestions.

Comment: Well, since you decap'd it, why not post a photo of the die? Much more useful stuff can be said by looking at that. The damage may not be visible without sufficient magnification though. See http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11243.pdf for some sample photos of various failure modes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [NXP AN11243](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11243.pdf) bonding wires only blow up if the current rating is exceeded. For "Unclamped Inductive Switching (UIS) - commonly called Avalanche or Ruggedness" failure, the bonding wires are still there, but there's usually a small round hole somewhere on the die. If instead you've exceeded the SOA (die temperature), you'll see a much larger burn area on the die. For ESD failures, it's very hard to see any damage without a microscope.

Hope this helps.